# How to get a casus belli against a country you don't border?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

As England is there any way I can manufacture a casus belli against Morocco so I don't have to take the -2 stability hit when I declare war?

It's currently 1478, and after winning the HYW I'm looking to get a foothold in Morocco to act as a stepping stone for colonising Southern Africa and then jumping across to South America.

I've tried warning them; insulting them and Embargoing them. No luck so far.

I've also tried giving them a loan on the hope that they fail to pay it back.. No luck there either.

I could become the Papal controller and declare a crusade against them in the hope that I get dragged into the war by allying myself with Castile or Portugal (Morocco's catholic neighbours who will get an additional casus belli against Morocco due to the crusade). But that could take a while.

Comment: Hmm.. Luckily for me I've just realised Portugal's King who is 63 has no heir, since I've maintained a Royal Marriage with Portugal since the start I was able to claim the throne. I suppose now it's just a waiting game until the current King dies and a Union is formed with Portugal (as long as no one else declares a claim before then).. 50 years later I'll be able to start to integrate them with Great Britain and I'll get all of their territory and cores without taking any hit what so ever.

Comment: Don't attack Morocco man, they have 2x coring costs. Almost never attack morocco imo. Try to get yourself into war against Castile and take some of iberia.

Comment: I didn't know that. What effects the coring cost of Morocco to make it 100% more than the usual?

Comment: @DMK I tested a bit curia controller and defender of the faith. You can definitely call a crusade, but that doesn't mean Castille or Portugal will act on it. You could also become Defender of the Faith, but that's a risky and expensive option. That's why I left it out of my answer.

Comment: By the sounds of it looking towards Castile or Portugal is definitely the best course of action.

Comment: It's not ideal ... but I think it's the best you can do right now. Feel free to accept a better answer, if someone chimes in later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it is easier for you to provoke war against Castille or whoever controls southern Iberia. You can fabricate claims to any neighbouring province, including those who are separated by a single sea province.

For example, if you control Cadiz or Granada, you should be able to fabricate a claim in Morocco, or possibly trigger a holy war casus belli.

Another option is to abandon the Morocco plans, and instead target the Azores. That way, you might be able to colonize Africa (depending on your colonial range) or make the jump to South America directly.

Comment: If I target the Azores won't I have much the same problem as they're owned by Portugal (Portugal not being a neighbour) from the start so I can't fabricate a claim on their territory but instead will have to manufacture some other casus belli?

Comment: Provoking Castille is definitely an option as they have me set as a rival and opinion is already low. However their military strength is much, much greater than Morocco and so the -2 stability hit may outweigh a prolonged war with a significant military power such as Castille.

Comment: You won't be able to fabricate a claim in the Azores directly, but it might be easier to get a war going with Portugal than Morocco – then grab the province and deal with the AE. If Castille isn't an option, are there any other countries who hold provinces in southern Iberia? Otherwise, maybe you can go through Algiers or something.

Also keep an eye out for other options. Look for any provinces near the Gibraltar straight, that can be conquered. Possibly this might extend your colonial range enough to settle south of Morocco?

Answer (score 3):

Another option to get an easy CB for England once it is Protestant is to take the first idea in the religious idea group; you are then free to declare war on most of Europe (if you play as a pagan nation, it gives you pretty much permanent CB against anyone).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get a cb against them would be the loan, but you mentioned it failed ( in which way? ) . Another way would be by enforcing peace . The easiest way would be to man up and tank that 2 stability hit .

Comment: It failed because they paid up on time..

Comment: The loan idea was essentially patched out a while back. Eg, it was one of the game mechanics DDRJake used to get the still only confirmed successful The Three Mountains run about a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a way to make the enemy angry (e.g. by insulting) so he will impose an embargo on you. That will give you a causus belli (trade dispute).

Note that you lose causus belli if you embargo him at same time, remove your embargo to get cuasus belli "trade dispute".